# Drupal 7 create blank page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming, drupal-panels

How to create blank page with Views || Panel || Display Suite modules?
Or
How to create blank page with theme-hook, like page--contentType.tpl.php
without fields?

Blank page for landing page or custom layout different with page.tpl.php regions?

I used [Empty page module](https://www.drupal.org/project/empty_page), but not worked for me!
How to create it?

I want to create image gallery page.

It's type of page from views module. views-view--gallery--page.tpl.php.

I need two different layout for page in page.tpl.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view gallery, then create a page with pane, assign that view to the content pane. Then, create a custom template with the **path** of the created page. Copy the code from the page.tpl.php and paste it in your custom template.

page--path.tpl.php

Comment: I want to create image gallery page.

It's type of page from views module. views-view--gallery--page.tpl.php.

I need two different layout for page in page.tpl.php

Comment: I edited my answer using panels. See if that works for you :)

Comment: My reputation score under 15, I vote it, when reached this score :)